# Using aws xray with apache

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

My understanding on aws xray is, xray is similar to dynatrace and I am trying to use xray for monitoring apache performance. I do not see any document related to xray with apache except below.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-xray-recorder-sdk-apache-http

Can anyone please suggest if it is possible to use aws xray with apache and if yes can you also point some document related to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "apache" you mean the Apache Tomcat servlet container, since you are referring to a maven artifact which is a Java build tool.

Disclamer: I don't know what "dynatrace" is and I don't know which logging you specifically want.

But as far as the Apache Tomcat servlet container and X-Ray goes - here is the link to get started:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java.html

> Start by adding AWSXRayServletFilter as a servlet filter to trace incoming requests. A servlet filter creates a segment While the segment is open you can use the SDK client's methods to add information to the segment and create subsegments to trace downstream calls. The SDK also automatically records exceptions that your application throws while the segment is open.

As for the mentioned maven artifact:

> aws-xray-recorder-sdk-apache-http – Instruments outbound HTTP calls made with Apache HTTP clients

So, you'll need this if, let's say, a client makes a request to your Tomcat server and your Tomcat server makes a request to another server thus acting as a client in this case.